# Postman giving error wrong server key even server key is correct?

Tags: php, api, postman

```html
<?php

header_remove('Server');
//header("Content-type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require('assets/init.php');

$api_versions      = array('1.0');
$response_data     = array();
$api_version       = (!empty($_GET['v']) && in_array($_GET['v'],$api_versions)) ? PT_Secure($_GET['v']) : '';
$api               = "api/v$api_version/api-v$api_version.php"; 

if (empty($_POST['server_key']) || $_POST['server_key'] != $pt->config->server_key) {
    $response_data       = array(
        'api_status'     => '404',
        'errors'         => array(
            'error_id'   => '1',
            'error_text' => 'Wrong server key'
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($response_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    exit();
}


if (!file_exists($api)) {
    $response_data       = array(
        'api_status'     => '404',
        'errors'         => array(
            'error_id'   => '1',
            'error_text' => 'Error: 404 API Version Not Found'
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($response_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    exit();
}



$type          = (!empty($_GET['type'])) ? PT_Secure($_GET['type']) : '';
$type          = ($_GET['type']) ? PT_Secure($_GET['type']) : '';
$applications  = array('phone');
$application   = (!empty($_GET['platform']) && in_array($_GET['platform'], $applications)) ? PT_Secure($_GET['platform']) : 'phone';
require_once   "$api";


echo json_encode($response_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
exit();

$db->disconnect();
unset($pt);
?>
```

[image]

I have set the correct server key for API and when I fetch data through postman it gives me an error wrong server key even my key is correct. I have completely studied the code line by line there is no error in the code about hours and hours I search but I did not get any solution.

Comment: I am note sure that the authentication method is using POST??
Remove the || $_POST['server_key'] != $pt->config->server_key to see if your post key is not simply empty.
Also are you sure this athentication methode is not crypting the key/value??

Comment: I did as you write and the request gets not post. now working

Comment: That means that you are trying to retrieve login data as post while you should try to retrieve them as headers parameters..